# How to fix a Mac Terminal that does not correctly prompt and display git commands?

Tags: bash, git, unix, terminal, osx-yosemite

I recently made some edits to my .bash_profile and my Mac terminal now lost many features and functionality for git

For example, a healthy terminal looked like this:
[healthy_terminal_with_git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP0Jr.png)

Now mine looks like this [unhealthy_terminal_without_git_functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU4v5.png)

As you can see, although my terminal is able to execute all the git commands, it is unable to display which branch I am in and there are no colors to indicate important git information as seen in a normal healthy terminal.

I uninstalled oh-my-zsh and deleted my bash profile on my local desktop (it will be reinstated from a git repository once I solve this git issue).  I have also reinstalled git on my terminal using homebrew.

If you have any good intuition for how to bring back the colors and git functionality of my terminal that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Restore your .bash_profile from a backup?

Comment: Check `set | grep ^PS1` in the working one, and compare to the broken one..

Comment: Install bash completion, make sure you have git completion, and just add `$(__git_ps1)` to your PS1 variable in your profile... just google this stuff, it's basic: https://gist.github.com/trey/2722934

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not an "unhealthy terminal". This is just an addon.

Add this to your `~/.bashrc` by

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Then copy in

```
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
export PS1="\u@\h \[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```

It will run `parse_git_branch` and parse the branch name from the stdout of `git branch`. Then using `Prompt String 1` print it on your terminal.